# Invalid content was found starting with element 'converter-for-class' in jsf

Tags: jsf

I use JSF for my project and I define a converter in faces-config.xml like bellow:

```
<converter>
  <description>myDateTimeConverter</description>
  <display-name>myDateTimeConverter</display-name>
  <converter-id>myDateTimeConverter</converter-id>
  <converter-for-class>java.util.Date</converter-for-class>
  <converter-class>controller.MyDateTimeConverter</converter-class>  
 </converter>
```

And I get an error in  (in eclipse):

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'converter-for-class'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":converter-class}' is 
 expected.
```

Comment: I copy this code from a tutorial. Then I don't think it have wrong in syntax

Answer (score 0):

Either use converter-id or either use converter-class. If you use id then JSF expects converter-class after it. That's why it says 'One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":converter-class}' is 
 expected.'. If you copied this from a tutorial, the tutorial contains an error ;-).

Comment: or the tutorial was for an older version where it was allowed

Comment: Nope. The ordering is just wrong. The `<converter-for-class>` itself is valid. It represents the same as JSF 2.0 `@FacesConverter(forClass=...)`.